# Repeating error on logcat: "FingerGoodix: Useless INT"

Tags: lineageos, sensors, fingerprint

I have a problem with a fingerprint scanner. It doesn't work no matter what firmware I use. I flashed different fixes but it didn't help. I captured a log and found these repetitive lines:

```
02-10 14:23:33.666  2432  2432 D FingerGoodix: Enter sig_handler ------<<<<<< ret = 0
02-10 14:23:33.667  2432  2432 D FingerGoodix: sig_handler 0x0126 = 0x0
02-10 14:23:33.667  2432  2432 D FingerGoodix: Useless INT
02-10 14:23:33.667  2432  2432 D FingerGoodix: Exit sig_handler ------>>>>>>
```

<sup>(Full log on https://paste.nomagic.uk/?9b40ef80e8a1caf8#8P3KTywk1M2Nw7hVEVe4uJT2uJJ9GPiZ3dUMFGVASMC9)</sup>

The fingerprint sensor worked with the original firmware, but when I flashed unofficial firmware and then tried to flash the original, it ceased to work.

So, can anyone explain what's wrong with it? I tried to google the error but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: ask your LineageOS maintainer to fix fingerprint sensor or flash complete stock firmware (including modem etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, the device has no official support anymore, and I flashed complete stock firmware through fastboot, didn't help.

Comment: get a list of partitions and compare which one is missing in 'complete' stock firmware

Comment: Thank you again, I'll try this approach.